# How to change Onedrive account?

Tags: onedrive, accounts

I'm currently using the automatic image synchronization option with Onedrive. But unfortunately all images are synced to the wrong account (account with 7GB of space instead of account with 25GB).

I'm **not** talking about Onedrive app, but feature built into Windows Phones

Comment: That still doesnt work, ive changed everything to a my new email, microsoft forgot to fix this bug, with wp8 out wp7 users are screwed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in feature always uses the Microsoft Account for this. You can change this only changing the entire Microsoft Account of the phone.

Comment: Oh noes... I've bought apps on this account. Is there a way to transfer them to another account?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you would have to reset the phone and start again as it links to the account you entered when you set up the phone

Answer (score 0):

Reset the phone and to transfer apps try this [answer here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/transfer-my-purchased-apps-from-one-account-to/eedb5e23-a687-4de7-aa31-469638ac25d2?auth=1) and this [forum](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8/219084-transferring-windows-phone-apps-new-microsoft-account.html).